# Why Julia is not indentation-based like Python?

Tags: indentation, julia, language-design

I really like the indentation-based syntax of Python; it makes code much more terse.

Is there a reason why Julia was not chosen to be indentation-based as well?

Please note that my intention is solely to learn about the motives that Julia developers had behind this decision; whether we agree or not with those motives is another discussion. I do not intend to start a never-ending discussion.

Comment: Slightly troll-ish question. Escaping indentation based syntax is perhaps one of Julia's *raison d'être*.

Comment: @user3580870 I do not mean to start a dicussion. My question is about what were the motives behind this design decision. Whether we agree or not with those motives is another discussion.

Comment: @user3580870 I think this is a good question.

Answer (score 33):

See this post on julia-users:
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/julia-users/lOmwPvOKc-o/discussion

From Stefan Karpinski

> It's a matter of taste – and the fact that we wanted Julia to feel familiar in particular to Matlab users (and to a lesser extent Ruby users). I personally don't like significant indentation. It gets really awkward and fiddly when you're trying to cut and paste into a terminal or into an editor. I've seen a significant number of live Python demos flounder as the presenter struggled with indentation issues. It feels to me like Python programs trail off into space with never-ending scopes. Jeff and Viral both happen to feel similarly, so Julia ended up looking more like Matlab than like Python.

Comment: Although that link is helpful, I think you need to provide a summary for this to be a complete answer. Adding a bullet-list outlining some of the key motivations would be good. (I personally like the points about auto-indenting and macros/meta-programming.)

Answer (score 0):

It was the taste of the developers (more matlab orientated). That is unfortunate for python users, who will miss more nice feature of python. See also https://groups.google.com/g/julia-users/c/itZDMNEoIW0/m/V-2YYpJdBmwJ

Comment: note that the choice to use `end` makes editing in the repl much easier. Julia knows that if you don't have an `end` you aren't writing your function. In python by contrast, the repl can't know if you are done writing your function.

Comment: In the end I have come to appreciate the fact that Julia is *not* indentation-based, more and more.